# Expanding grid area without collapsing row

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make `.item8` to expand on `.item2` and `.item3`. Can someone help?

When I make `.item8` to `1 / 2 / span 2 / span 5`, then it flatters to only first row.

Just like this:

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item8 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 2 / span 4;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 /1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
  <div class="item10">10</div>
  <div class="item11">11</div>
  <div class="item12">12</div>
  <div class="item13">13</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a height for the rows or the grid container. This means that rows will default to `grid-auto-rows: auto` (content-based height) and the grid container will manage grid items based on the [auto-placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#common-uses-auto-placement) and the [track sizing algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-track-sizing).

Keep it simple. Define a height on the container and/or define a height for the rows.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* new */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item8 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 2 / span 5; /* adjustment */
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
  <div class="item10">10</div>
  <div class="item11">11</div>
  <div class="item12">12</div>
  <div class="item13">13</div>
</div>
```